# C++ -Problems in Stacking an array

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, stack

I've been trying to figure out why my code isn't working correctly for the past few hours. Everything looks perfectly fine to me unless it's something I don't know about. I have asked my professor, but he can't seem to figure it out either. This code will completely ignore the if else statement in the **push** member function and will keep pushing after reaching the limit (in this case it's 5 elements). When it goes over the 5th element, and I check for the top, it shows the first implementation (element 0). I tried changing around my code by switching the member functions outside the class via scope resolution, but it's still no use. A different set of eyes would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

class Stack
{
private:
    static const int size = 5;
    double myarr[size];
    int t;

public:
    Stack() { t = -1; }
    void push(double element);
    void pop();
    void top();
    void menu();
};

void Stack::push(double element)
{
    if (t < size) {
        t++;
        myarr[t] = element;
    }
    else
        cout << "Stack Limit Reach !!!" << endl;
}

void Stack::pop()
{
    if (t >= 0) {
        cout << "Element : " << myarr[t] << " was popped off the Stack " << endl;
        t--;
    }
    else
        cout << "No more elemnts in the Stack !!!" << endl;
}

void Stack::top()
{
    if (t >= 0) {
        cout << "Element : " << myarr[t] << " is at the top of the Stack " << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "No more elemnts in the Stack !!!" << endl;
}

void Stack::menu()
{
    char choice = 'y';
    int pick;
    double elem;

    while (toupper(choice) == 'Y');//while(choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y');
    {
        cout << "1. Push" << endl;
        cout << "2. Pop" << endl;
        cout << "3. Top" << endl;
        cout << "4. Exit" << endl;
        cin >> pick;

        switch (pick)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "Enter the element: ";
            cin >> elem;
            cout << endl;
            push(elem);
            break;
        case 2:
            pop();
            break;
        case 3:
            top();
            break;
        case 4:
            choice = 'N';
            break;

        default:
            cout << "Please select 1-4" << endl;
        }
        system("pause");
    }


}

int main()
{
    Stack obj;
    obj.menu();

};
```

Comment: sorry to give a seeming facetious comment (its not intended) , but did you try stepping through it with a debugger? `while (toupper(choice) == 'Y');` should not end with a semi colon, could that be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

In your example code, the stack's `size` is 5 (which means array `myarr` has valid indices `0` through `4`).

```
void Stack::push(double element)
{
    if (t < size) {
        t++;
        myarr[t] = element;
    }
    else
        cout << "Stack Limit Reach !!!" << endl;
}
```

Consider the case when `t` here is `4`.  The `if` tests true, so the block to add to `myarr` is entered.  First thing that happens is you increment `t`, which is now `5`.  Then you use that as the index to store the value into `myarr`, which is out of bounds.

Try something like:

```
void Stack::push(double element)
{
    if (t < size) {
        myarr[t++] = element;
    }
    else
        cout << "Stack Limit Reach !!!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: to go along with that, you'd probably want to intitialise `t` to 0 in the constructor. Otherwise the first call to pop access index -1 of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You skip myarr[0] then 5th element is saved to myarr[5] that is 6th element in myarr! (Accessing to elements of an array by index is zero based in C++)

Change:

```
    Stack() { t = -1; }
```

to:

```
    Stack() { t = 0; }
```

and

```
    if (t < size) {
    t++;
    myarr[t] = element;
```

to:

```
    if (t < size) {
        myarr[t++] = element;
```

Comment: Could be better. This solution wastes element 0.

Comment: Even when t starts with -1?

Comment: Son of a gun. It does start at -1. My apologies. OP is working from a weak design, but that's not your fault.

Comment: I agree, starting with 0 is better, actually I am going to edit my answer!

Answer (score 0):

You are allowing 6 elements to be pushed onto the stack, and there's only room for 5.

Change:

```
 if (t < size) {
   t++;
```

to:

```
 if (t < size-1) {
    t++;
```

Answer (score 0):

I understood your problem when you are searching for the top element you are not getting because whenever the stack becomes full for ex:-

assume you are inserting(below mentioned code) 5th element in 4th index it will be inserted and the value of t get incremented to 5 due to t++.

```
    void Stack::push(double element)
{
    if (t < size) {
        t++;
        myarr[t] = element;
    }
    else
        cout << "Stack Limit Reach !!!" << endl;
}
```

but at the same time when you call top() function it checks for the index, and obviously 5 is greater that 0 so it enters the loop but index 5 contains '\0' 
Character so there is an ambiguity with compiler

```
    void Stack::top()
{
    if (t >= 0) {
        cout << "Element : " << myarr[t] << " is at the top of the Stack " << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "No more elemnts in the Stack !!!" << endl;
}
```

So the change that is required for the above code is just put a if statement by saying the compiler that if the stack is full then decrement t value by 1

```
void Stack::top()
{
    if (t >= 0) {
            if(t==size){t--;}
        cout << "Element : " << myarr[t] << " is at the top of the Stack " << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "No more elemnts in the Stack !!!" << endl;
}
```

This may give you correct result